# Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop of type `array` expected `object` with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So this line of code is throwing something like ' Failed propType: Invalid prop of type `array` expected `object`.'

Why is this happening?

Here is my JSON:

```
"student_records": [
      {
        "program": "PSCI-210",
        "grade": 80
      }
    ]
```

jsx:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';


const StudentRecordPropTypes = {
  studentRecordData: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function StudentRecord(props) {
    const Records = props.studentRecordData;


  return (
    <div>
        {(Records || []).map(student_records => (
              <ul>
                    <li>{student_records.program} : {student_records.grade} </li>
              </ul>
            ))}
    </div>
  );
}
StudentRecord.propTypes = StudentRecordPropTypes;

export default StudentRecord;
```

It displays correctly. After some googling, I realized that its looking to an array but its infact an object. My problem is that I don't know how to fix it. How can I remove this error?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Change

```
const StudentRecordPropTypes = {
  studentRecordData: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

to

```
const StudentRecordPropTypes = {
  studentRecordData: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: Yay thank you! Is there any suggestions you could make to the return function without changing it to an array?

Comment: "students_records" is an array, so it has to be an array, why do you think it's an object?

Comment: How do you solve this if array, object or any are not allowed?

Comment: Hi @SBD have you solved this? I'm also "forbidden to use array". Crap!